# How to unconcatenate a date into individual combo boxes using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, date, combobox, concatenation

I'm using a form to populate a sheet in Excel. In the form, the date-related boxes are broken up by day-month-year combo boxes, which are concatenated to populate a single cell in the sheet. My question is whether there is a way to "unconcatenate" a date in a single cell and populate each individual combo box with the appropriate information (day, month, or year). This is because I want to be able to add new information in one form, then update what already exists in the table in another form.

Code to update form based on given parameter below (focus in **Bold**):

```
Private Sub txtstudynm_Change()

Dim StudyName As String
Dim WrdString As String
Dim text_string As String


If Me.txtstudynm.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Study Name can not be blank", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

StudyName = txtstudynm.Value

On Error Resume Next
Me.cmbprojman.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(StudyName, Sheets("Study Summary").Range("A3:AJ3000"), 2, 0)

On Error Resume Next
Me.cmbstudtyp.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(StudyName, Sheets("Study Summary").Range("A3:AJ3000"), 3, 0)

On Error Resume Next
Me.cmbprogtyp.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(StudyName, Sheets("Study Summary").Range("A3:AJ3000"), 4, 0)

On Error Resume Next
Me.cmbfundtyp.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(StudyName, Sheets("Study Summary").Range("A3:AJ3000"), 5, 0)

On Error Resume Next
Me.txtbudget.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(StudyName, Sheets("Study Summary").Range("A3:AJ3000"), 6, 0)

On Error Resume Next
Me.txtencumb.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(StudyName, Sheets("Study Summary").Range("A3:AJ3000"), 7, 0)

On Error Resume Next
Me.cmbpath.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(StudyName, Sheets("Study Summary").Range("A3:AJ3000"), 8, 0)

**On Error Resume Next**

**text_string = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(StudyName, Sheets("Study Summary").Range("A3:AJ3000"), 9, 0).Value**  

**WrdString = Split(text_string, "/")(0)** 

**Me.tssdcmb1.Value = WrdString**

On Error Resume Next
Me.tssdcmb2.Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(StudyName, Sheets("Study Summary").Range("A3:AJ3000"), 9, 0)

On Error Resume Next
Me.tssdcmb3.Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(StudyName, Sheets("Study Summary").Range("A3:AJ3000"), 9, 0)

End Sub
```

Comment: One note, Unless you use `On Error Goto 0` to reset the error catch you only need one `On Error Goto Next`.  It is not a one line thing but turns off the error reporting till it gets reset.

Comment: Is `Sheets("Study Summary").Range("I:I")` formatted as `Date` and containing values Excel understands as `Date` values? Or they're `String` values that *look* like dates?

Comment: If your date is a date then the value being passed is not text but a number and as such you would use `Month(text_string)` to return the month number.

Comment: The `.Range("A3:AJ3000")` is the entire area of the sheet where it's possible to input data. So the columns where dates would be are formatted as date, and the other columns are general. Also, I've tried using the `Month()` function but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: "I've tried using the Month() function but it doesn't seem to be working" - how so? if it's not working, then your dates aren't `Date` values. "columns are formatted as date" doesn't mean "Exel understands the values as proper dates". `IsDate` will tell you if they're dates. Ignoring all runtime errors with `On Error Resume Next` is a good way to make this very hard to debug, too.

Comment: After you combine all three answers into one robust solution go read [Userform.Show](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) by @MathieuGuindon and start some good habits how to use Userforms before it's too late.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback. I've been able to get the information to display in the combo box, however, I think the root of the problem is my formatting. Instead of appearing as "12/4/2018" or a piece thereof, it appears as "43438". I'm not sure if it's possible to parse this value into day/month/year, or if it's a symptom of a different problem in my code/formatting. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @M.Terry please choose one of the answers below that is the most correct, the one you relied on the most that solved the problem.  It will remove this question from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of all those references to the worksheet, use a Variant array:

```
Private Sub txtstudynm_Change()

If Me.txtstudynm.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Study Name can not be blank", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim StudyName As String
StudyName = txtstudynm.Value

Dim lkp As Variant
lkp = Sheets("Study Summary").Range("A3:AJ3000").Value2

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To UBound(lkp, 1)
    If lkp(i, 1) = StudyName Then
        Me.cmbprojman.Value = lkp(i, 2)
        Me.cmbstudtyp.Value = lkp(i, 3)
        Me.cmbprogtyp.Value = lkp(i, 4)
        Me.cmbfundtyp.Value = lkp(i, 5)
        Me.txtbudget.Value = lkp(i, 6)
        Me.txtencumb.Value = lkp(i, 7)
        Me.cmbpath.Value = lkp(i, 8)
        Me.tssdcmb1.Value = Day(lkp(i, 9))
        Me.tssdcmb2.Value = Month(lkp(i, 9))
        Me.tssdcmb3.Value = Year(lkp(i, 9))
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this (not sure which Combo Box you set to Day/Month/Year)...

```
Dim StudyDate as Date
If IsDate(text_string) Then
    StudyDate = CDate(txt)
    Me.tssdcmb1.Value Day(StudyDate)
    Me.tssdcmb2.Value Month(StudyDate)
    Me.tssdcmb3.Value Year(StudyDate)
End If
```

Comment: Using `IsDate` to validate the string instead of assuming its format is very robust, +1.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `text_string` as a proper `Date` value (and this is why you don't encode a variable's data type in its name). Then the VLOOKUP will yield a `Date` value:

```
text_string = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(StudyName, Sheets("Study Summary").Range("A3:AJ3000"), 9, 0).Value
```

If what you have is a proper `Date`, then you use the `VBA.DateTime.Year`, `VBA.DateTime.Month`, and `VBA.DateTime.Day` functions to get each part:

```
Me.tssdcmb1.Value = Year(text_string)
Me.MonthBox.Value = Month(text_string)
Me.DayBox.Value = Day(text_string)
```

Notice how meaningful, pronounceable names make the code easier to read/follow.

---

If what you have is really a *string that looks like a date*, then... you better hope that the format is consistent, and then using the `VBA.Strings.Split` function like you did wasn't a bad idea - just use the 3 indices you got:

```
Dim dateParts As Variant
dateParts = Split(text_string, "/")

Me.YearBox.Value = dateParts(0)
Me.MonthBox.Value = dateParts(1)
Me.DayBox.Value = dateParts(2)
```